# cascading combobox is not updating itemsource of dependent combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I have two comboboxes

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbInstanceList" Margin="15,0,5,0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding InstanceList}" SelectionChanged="cmbInstanceList_SelectionChanged"

                              Height="25" 
                              Style="{StaticResource InputControlErrorsCombo}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"  />    
<ComboBox x:Name="cmbDatabaseList" Margin="15,0,5,0" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding DatabaseList}"

                              Height="25" Style="{StaticResource InputControlErrorsCombo}" Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}" />
```

Here, based on **cmbInstanceList**, I fill **cmbDatabaseList** through Itemsource property. **InstanceList** and **DatabaseList** are model properties of type List.

In code back-end I am using selectionchanged event to fill the second combobox.

```
private void cmbInstanceList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (cmbInstanceList.SelectedValue != null)
            {
                this.data.InstanceName = cmbInstanceList.SelectedValue.ToString();
                this.data.DatabaseList.Clear(); // this is not working
                FillData(this.data.InstanceName);
            }
        }
```

where this.data represents the model class which contains all the properties.

FillData method contains a call to service and if data is not available the return data values will be just an empty list.

```
response = service.RequestDatabasesByInstance(request);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    if (response.DatabaseList != null && response.DatabaseList.Any())
                        this.data.DatabaseList = response.DatabaseList.ToList<string>();
                    else
                    {
                        this.data.DatabaseList.Clear();
                        throw new Exception("No data available");
                    }
                }
```

Problem: when I select the value from cmbInstance and service returns the response with the list with values, all good and working fine.
When I select the value, where service is not able to retrieve the data and returns the empty list there is a problem. even though, I set the model property to clear the items, on UI I can still see combobox contains the values and items are not getting cleared.

Comment: is `DatabaseList` `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: @LeiYang its List<string> .will it work with ObservableCollection ?

Comment: in wpf you'd better bind `ObservableCollection` with ui

Comment: @LeiYang well, I don't think so it may have any impact with the approach that I've used

Comment: You're calling `this.data.DatabaseList = ...` in one case and `data.DatabaseList.Clear()` in the other. In order to make the first case work with data binding, the DatabaseList property must fire a PropertyChanged event (i.e. its owning class must implement INotifyPropertyChanged). For the second case, the list must implement INotifyCollectionChanged, e.g. be an ObservableCollection.

Comment: @Clemens , Got your point totally. when you were typing the root cause , I was updating my answer. Kudos to your geniusness :) it worked for me without using ObservableCollection or INotifyCollectionChanged. I am still using the list<string> and is working fine now

Answer (score 0):

> I have forgotten the basic concepts of MVVM

You don't seem to know what the MVVM pattern is all about...

Handling the `SelectionChanged` event in the view to implement cascading ComboBoxes is *not* MVVM.

Instead you should populate the source collection of the second `ComboBox` when the source property that is bound to the `SelectedItem` property of the first `ComboBox` is set. There is a full example and more information available in the following blog post: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/06/17/cascading-comboboxes-in-wpf-using-mvvm/.

There should be *zero* code in the code-behind related to the cascading `ComboBoxes` if you follow the MVVM pattern. The solution you have presented here doesn't follow the MVVM design pattern.

Answer (score -1):

I have forgotten the basic concepts of MVVM.
I believe this answer may help someone like me who are trying to find the grass in the space.

The resolution to the problem is: 
I have changed

> this.data.DatabaseList.Clear(); // this is not working

to

> this.data.DatabaseList= null;

and it started working.

Technically, when we change the value of the property, firing the `PropertyChanged` event (declared in the INotifyPropertyChanged interface)  notifies the Binding, which then updates the view. In my case, I was just clearing the collection object held by the property, which was not firing the PropertyChanged event.

Hope this helps someone.